# Algebraic structures and axiomatic systems

Tags: abstract-algebra, axioms, binary-operations

In one textbook appears the following sentence:

> An **algebraic structure** is a nonempty set $M$ together with one or more operations (i.e. a function $*:M\times M\rightarrow M$) which satisfy some axioms. In other words, the definition of an algebraic structure is an axiomatic system. It can be proved that an axiomatic system which defines an algebraic structure verifies the logic requirements which any axiomatic system has to fulfill.

My question is: what does an algebraic structure need to fulfill (I mean the logic requirements)? It's about consistency or something like that? (The authors of the book say that the frame of the book doesn't allow that)

Comment: What book is this? "The logic requirements which an axiomatic system has to fulfil" sounds like nonsense to me. If it does make sense in context it must depend on somwhatt unusual definitions given elsewhere in the book.  (That "i.e." is also very suspect: operations aren't usually all required to be binary.)

Comment: In this book are discussed only binary operations, so that is not a problem for me. It's about some conditions algebraic structures must fulfill (as axiomatic systems) which I don't know!

Comment: OK, ignore the part of my comment in brackets. Your qeuestion can't be answered without some context, e.g., the title of the book.

Comment: They don't mention such a condition. In my knowledge, an axiomatic system is a list with some undefined terms and some statements. It must also lack of a contradiction. I don't know what other properties this needs to have.

Comment: If you are not willing to tell us what book you are talking about, then it is not possible to answer the question.

Comment: "Matematică M1: manual pentru clasa a XII / Marcel Țena, Marian Andronache" This is from Romania and the translation is correct. There is no other sentence which could lead to some context.

Comment: Sorry: are these course notes rather than a published book? If so, then I think you will have to ask your teacher as the quotation makes no sense without additional context.

Comment: That is the whole context...

Comment: @RobArthan: Usually, what does an axiomatic system need?

Answer (score 1):

All I can do is give you some pointers to the standard terminology of elementary model theory and universal algebra: a *structure* consists of a set equipped with a set of finitary operations and relations (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_(mathematical_logic). An *algebraic structure* is one in which the only relation is equality (which many authors treat as a logical rather than mathematical concept) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_structure). It is usual to associate a fixed set names for the operations and relations used in a structure. Such an association is called a *signature* for the structure and results in a logical language with function and relation symbols for the operations and relations. An *axiomatic system* is just a set of axioms in a logical language (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiomatic_system). Any set of axioms in the language defined by some signature defines a class of structures for its signature (namely the structures in which those axioms hold) and conversely a class of structures for a signature defines a set of axioms (namely the axioms which hold in each structure in the class). A class of algebraic structures defined by a set of equational axioms is called an *algebraic variety* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_variety).

There are no special requirements on axiomatic systems in normal usage, so in the last sentence in your quotation there is nothing to prove given the standard interpretations of the terminology involved.